# draggableCancel on react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using [react grid layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) with [amcharts3-react](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-react) everything is just fine, I can move elements around but, this time I can't use amcarts Zoom handles... They are draggable as well.I tried to use grid layout's cancelDraggable feature but nothing happened. even it didn't prevent the area that I specify for nonedragging. What could be the possible solution?

[image]

```html
                <GridLayout>
                  <div key="d" data-grid={{x: 4, y: 0, w: 4, h: 2, draggableHandle: '.dragHandle', draggableCancel:'.noneDraggable'}}>
                    <span className="dragHandle">[DRAG HERE]</span>
                    <div className="noneDraggable">
                      <Chart />
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div key="c" data-grid={{x: 0, y: 0, w: 4, h: 2}}>
                    <Chart />
                  </div>

                </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved by associating the property to the dashboard itself, not the items, like so:

```
<ResponsiveReactGridLayout 
  rowHeight={75}
  layouts={this.props.dashboard.record.layout} 
  onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange.bind(this)}
  onDragStop={this.onDragStop.bind(this)}
  draggableCancel='.dashboard-item-content' 
  draggableHandle='.dashboard-item-header'
  onResizeStop={this.onResizeStop.bind(this)}>
    {this.generateDOM()}
</ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

Try to associate the 2 properties to your GridLayout jsx node.

Comment: Hi sir I have one issue regarding `react-grid-layout`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438916/how-to-create-dynamic-drag-and-drop-layout-with-react-grid-layout

This is my post I have put please check the edited part once, it will be great if you can help.