# How to create dynamic drag and drop layout with react-grid-layout

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, grid-layout, react-grid-layout

I am using [react-grid-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout) to make `drag-drop and resize components`, So i am able to achieve the functionality as mentioned in the doc.

**My Issue**

- I am creating dynamic UI so I am rendering my UI with data.
- Here in this library I need to create layout like `{ {i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2}`
- When I am creating static UI I am able to achieve what I want.[Here is working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-panini-qw6j7?file=/src/App.js)

In static Ui with predefined  layout I did like below.

```
    const layout = [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 },
    { i: "b", x: 2, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 },
    { i: "c", x: 4, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 },
    { i: "d", x: 6, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 },
    { i: "e", x: 0, y: 2, w: 2, h: 1 }
  ];

<div className="App">
  <GridLayout
    className="layout"
    layout={layout}
    style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
  >
    {layout.map((li) => (
      <div key={li.i} style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
        {li.i}
      </div>
    ))}
  </GridLayout>
```

This is working fine, But here the layout I have defined is static, So for this I searched and got one example with dynamic height and width, which is creating a dynamic layout.

But that is creating the layout with just random numbers which is not showing up with my UI (as per my use), [This is what I found out in library for dynamic UI](https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/10-dynamic-min-max-wh.html)

**What I am trying to do**

I have this data as in my state

```
const [data1, setData] = useState({
    EmpData: [
        {
            empId: 11,
            lay1: { i: 'a' },
            data: [
                {
                    firstName: 'Steve',
                    lastName: 'Smith',
                },
                {
                    firstName: 'Michel',
                    lastName: 'Muner',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            empId: 12,
            lay1: { i: 'b' },
            data: [
                {
                    firstName: 'Charles',
                    lastName: 'Johnsen',
                },
                {
                    firstName: 'Glen',
                    lastName: 'Tyson',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            empId: 13,
            lay1: { i: 'c' },
            data: [
                {
                    firstName: 'Steve',
                    lastName: 'Smith',
                },
                {
                    firstName: 'Michel',
                    lastName: 'Muner',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            empId: 14,
            lay1: { i: 'd' },
            data: [
                {
                    firstName: 'Steve',
                    lastName: 'Smith',
                },
                {
                    firstName: 'Michel',
                    lastName: 'Muner',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            empId: 15,
            lay1: { i: 'e' },
            data: [
                {
                    firstName: 'Steve',
                    lastName: 'Smith',
                },
                {
                    firstName: 'Michel',
                    lastName: 'Muner',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
});
```

By above data I am creating Ui as per my need

```
return data1.EmpData.map((li, index) => (
        <div key={index.toString()} data-grid={index}"> </div> //what should I pass here as key and layout that I am not getting
            <>
                {li.data.map((l) => (
                    <>
                        <div>{l.firstName}</div>
                        <div>{l.lastName}</div>
                    </>
                ))}
            </>
        </div>
    ));
};
```

Passing `key` and creating dynamic `layout` is where I am not able to figure out how can I achieve this, as this is totally new thing to me.

My UI is totally dynamic Every time I am going to get dynamic data so that much cards or divs I need to show.

[Here is my code sand box what I am trying to do dynamically](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-rain-2000e?file=/src/App.js:0-1892)

**Edit / Update**

The answer I got from `@Daniil Loban` is very helpfull, but when I am trying to loop with my real time data it is looping twice, **That is hapenning because my data is little bit different of what I have shown here**

Actually I am not able to understand `I use data1.EmpData[l.i] to get data to display when I map layout.` this line.

**My data**

```
    [
{
  compId: 5,
  company_name: "Info",
  comp_data: [
    {
      empId: 1,
      empName:"steve"
    },
    {
      empId: 2,
      empName:"meg"
    }
  ]
},
{
  compId: 6,
  company_name: "wipro",
  comp_data: [
    {
      empId: 11,
      empName:"mark"
    },
    {
      empId: 12,
      empName:"Tnml"
    }
  ]
}
```

]

- How data goes is like company->employ of that company->data of that company,
- So here company can be multiple employ can be multiple similarly for data
- What i have updated in previous data I have not mentioned the company as I thought of writing minimal code.
- I have added full code Now and [Here is my code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-burnell-fz7lu?file=/src/App.js:604-1043)

**The issue**

- Issue is it is repeating the data, I am getting duplicate data on display
- I ll explain here like  `company namme->companydata->employe name` this should be the perfect but what is happening is  -- companyname->the in one div both employ I a, getting and in other again I am getting both ones

[image: Here is the image which is showing wrong data]

It should be for `Info` there are two employ so in one grid one employ and in other one the other employ.

**The issue is in `generateDOM` this function as layout is generated perfectly but in one Layout it is repeating all then same for others, if lenght is 3 then it is creating 3 layouts which is totally fine, but inside one layout it is agian looping and showing duplicate data**

**Here by I am attaching one image how it should show on UI [image: This is whaqt I am trying to achieve]**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem was that layout was not used, I also noticed the incorrect use of random from lodash (but this is not essential)

I use `data1.EmpData[l.i]` to get data to display when I map `layout`.

I also created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-panini-6djzi?file=/src/App.js:2216-2234) where there is a button for dynamic addition, I think this is what you wanted.

```
  const generateDOM = () => {
    // Generate items with properties from the layout, rather than pass the layout directly
    const layout = generateLayout();
    return _.map(layout, function (l) {
      return (
        <div key={l.i} data-grid={l} className="bg-success">
          <>
            <div className="rounded" key="?"></div>
            {data1.EmpData[l.i].data.map((l) => (
              <>
                <div>{l.firstName}</div>
                <div>{l.lastName}</div>
              </>
            ))}
          </>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

For updated question:

[image]

```
  const generateDOM = (lo) => {
    // Generate items with properties from the layout, rather than pass the layout directly
    const layout = generateLayout();
    return _.map(layout, function (l) {
      return (
        <div key={l.i} data-grid={l} className="bg-success">
          <div>{lo[l.i].empName}</div>
          {console.log(lo, l, active_menu)}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

And when we render, `we don't need map`, but just one call:

```
  return (
    <>
      {data1.map((d, ind) => (
        <div className={ind === active_menu ? "compNameActive" : "compName"}>
          <p onClick={() => compClick(ind)}>{d.company_name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
      <ReactGridLayout onLayoutChange={onLayoutChange} {...props}>
        {generateDOM(data1[active_menu].comp_data)}
      </ReactGridLayout>
    </>
  );
```

[sanbox2](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-rgb-6rzzt?file=/src/App.js:1939-2312)

Comment: I followed you code and it is working fine for making the layout, the issue I am getting is with duplicate creation of data, I have edited my post and added new `code sandbox` please check one I don't know what i am missing

Comment: Actually I am not able to understand `I use data1.EmpData[l.i] to get data to display when I map layout.` this line

Comment: Hey I wanted to ask one thing, Why this `onLayoutChange` is not triggering, I have checked yor code as well as mine, when I do in class component it works fine

Comment: Hi, I don't know, but if it works in a class component I would use it.

Comment: Hi I have One issue similar to this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66675196/storing-layout-for-my-react-app-in-local-storage-not-working  Could you please check one.

Answer (score 2):

The layout should be an object containing the layout data, including an id `i` to store the relation to other data:

```
[
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 },
          ^------- The id to store the relation to other data
]
```

You need to build the layout first, either in a way that you choose, or directly from your emp-data. Only **the id `i` has to match** your emp-data, the other values are "independant" layout data.

*Note that my example requires the `empId` to be unique (there is duplication in your example).*

E.g.:

```
const generateLayout = () => {
  let totalIndex = -1;
  return data1.EmpData.reduce( (accEmp, empItem, empIndex) => {
    return accEmp.concat(
      empItem.data.map( (dataItem, index) => {
        const w = _.random(1, 2);
        const h = _.random(1, 3);
        totalIndex++;
        return {
          x: (totalIndex * 2) % 12,
          y: Math.floor(totalIndex / 6),
          w: w,
          h: h,
          i: empItem.empId + '-' + index
        };
      })
    );
  }, []);
}
```

Then, to display the content, you can iterate over the *layout* data, and find the elements to display by the id `i` stored in the layout.
E.g.:

```
const generateDOM = () => {
  const layout = generateLayout();

  return layout.map((ly, index) => {
    const [ empIndex, dataIndex ] = ly.i.split('-');

    const empItem = data1.EmpData.find( eI => eI.empId.toString() === empIndex );
    const dataItem = empItem.data[ dataIndex ];

    return (
      <div key={ly.i} className="bg-success">
        <div className="rounded" key="?"></div>
        <>
          <div>{dataItem.firstName}</div>
          <div>{dataItem.lastName}</div>
        </>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

I think you can also do it the other way around, i.e. iterate over your emp-data, and find the matching layout item. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I have edited and given unique id, could you please share one working example.

Comment: It works if you just replace you functions `generateLayout` and `generateDOM` with mine.

Comment: I tried but it didn't, it would be much helpfull if i got to see one working example

Comment: Then I am sorry, I must have misunderstood you. When I insert my code into your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-panini-qw6j7?file=/src/App.js), it works as I expect it should. If that is still wrong, then I must have misunderstood the goal.

Comment: FYI: My previous comment is not true, since the code in the linked codesandbox has changed. (sorry that I didn't check before posting the link).

Comment: I have edited my post with proper details, please check if you can help.