# Storing layout for my react app in local storage not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-grid-layout

I am working with [react-grid-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout) and creating some grids which are drag-drop as well as resizable.

So i am able to achieve that and it is working fine.

My UI is like I have two tabs and each tab have some grids, so when I move from one tab two other I am showing that tab's grid.

**What I am trying to do**

On change of layout I want to store that layout to local storage so that when I refresh or open that tab again the formation of grid should be the one which I changed.

So as per mentioned [in library I am using this](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/8-localstorage-responsive.jsx)

- So what I am doing is when ever `onLayoutChange` happens I am storing the layout with respect to my `active_tab` and when I change from one to other tab I am checking Local storage and matching which tab is active and getting that particular layout.
- But this is not happening it is just taking the basic layout.

**What I did**

```
    function getFromLS(key) {
  let ls = {};
  if (global.localStorage) {
    try {
      ls =
        JSON.parse(
          global.localStorage.getItem(localStorage.getItem("active_tab"))
        ) || {};
    } catch (e) {
      /*Ignore*/
    }
    return ls[key];
  }
}
function saveToLS(key, value) {
  if (global.localStorage) {
    global.localStorage.setItem(
      localStorage.getItem("active_tab"),
      JSON.stringify({
        [key]: value
      })
    );
  }
}
```

- Onchange function of layout

  ```
   const onLayoutChange = (layout, layouts) => {
   saveToLS("layouts", layouts);
   console.log("onchange");
   setlayouts({ layouts });
    };
  ```

**Edit / Update**

I have updated my code sandbox as earlier it was taking layouts on console ans `undefined` now it is taking the layout, [Here is the updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-river-j58kg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Put a `console.log(layouts)` inside `onLayoutChange`. That's the first step to debug this. See if `layouts` object is as you intended or not.

Comment: Yes I did all this

Comment: Can you share the result of those `logs` ? Are you seeing the correct value as intended or not ? Such details help to debug faster.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I can share but you can also check, I have shared code sandbox Link for these things, the log is bit bigger you can se https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-river-j58kg?file=/src/App.js  here.

As I checked it is taking undefined, Which I don't know how ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I have edited my post and included updated code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-river-j58kg?file=/src/App.js  here the console is showing the layouts you can check.

Comment: Hey, @manishthakur did you achieve this, I have the same problem cannot save in local storage, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is run `generateDOM` once for each `active_menu`:

```
  const [DOM, setDOM] = useState(null)  

  useEffect(() => {
    setDOM(generateDOM(data1[active_menu].comp_data))
  }, [data1, active_menu]);
```

`data1` should also be in dependencies because need to recalculate `"DOM"` when adding and removing elements.

render:

```
  <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
    {...props}
    onLayoutChange={(layout, layouts) => onLayoutChange(layout, layouts)}
    layouts={layouts}
    cols={{ lg: 12, md: 4, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
  >
    {DOM} 
  </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

also I changed `localStorage.getItem("active_tab")` to `active_menu`

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsivereactgridlayout-zidq1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Sir I tried you code and it worked fine, but I got to ask one question i.e how to do conditional rendering.
if case `empName==="steve`  then w = 6 `else` 4
I tried 
`if (item.empName === "steve") {
          return {
            x: (i * 2) % 12,
            y: Math.floor(i / 6),
            w: 2,
            h: 4,
            i: i.toString()
          };
        } else {
          return {
            x: (i * 2) % 12,
            y: Math.floor(i / 6),
            w: 4,
            h: 2,
            i: i.toString()
          };
        }`

I tried with this but not worked